# <c:if> tag for JSF page

Tags: jsp, jsf, tags, if-statement

Used to develop Portlets and JPS's, so have a dilemma.

task: display `<h:dataTable>` only when list isn't empty

Is it possible to provide `<c:if>` tag for JSF page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can add JSTL tags in your JSF pages. However, in your case, you can simply do the following:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.list}"... rendered="#{myBean.displayTable}">
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

with the following method in `myBean`:

```
public boolean isDisplayTable() {
    return list != null && list.size() > 0;
}
```

You can also try that (not sure if it will work):

```
<!-- Idea from Colin Gislason -->
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.list}"... rendered="#{not empty myBean.list}">
    ...
</h:dataTable>

<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.list}"... rendered="#{not myBean.list.empty}">
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

Note that you can use the `!` instead of the `not` keyword in the EL expressions (see a guide [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) about EL expressions), which results in `rendered="#{!empty myBean.list}"`.

Comment: Your second example could also be rendered="#{! empty myBean.list}", since 'empty' is a standard JSF EL operator. I prefer to use the first method because it keeps the EL simpler if you ever have to add more conditions.

Answer (score 1):

`<c:if>` (and other JSTL tags) can be used in JSF in most cases. However, the cannot be used inside components that iterate on collections - like `<h:dataTable>`. But in your case, you want the `<c:if>` outside, so it is possible. However, as romaintaz pointed, it's better to use the `rendered` attribute.